# Suggestion on Encryption Algorithm to use for an SSH Key Vault Application

Tags: encryption, aes, rsa

I am building an SSH Key vault for use inhouse for my company. Users will upload their public keys (and optionally private keys) and the application will sync the public keys with the servers the user has access to.

For the optional feature of storing Private Key also (as a backup), I would like to make sure the keys are encrypted when uploaded to storage and want it to be decryptable only by the user.

I can do this two ways. I need your advice on which one is better:

1. Generate an AES 256 bit key locally on the user's browser, encrypt the key with the master password provided by the user, and send this encrypted key to the server to store. The advantage here is that generating key, encryption and decryption is fast since it is AES. The disadvantage is that the user will need to enter a master password each time he wants to store or retrieve the SSH Private Key.
2. Generate an RSA Key pair and send the generated public key and encrypted private key (with the master password provided by the user, and send them to the server to store. The advantage is that to store SSH Private keys, I do not need the user's master password, since I'll use his public key to encrypt the data. I'll need the master password only while retrieving the SSH Private Key. The disadvantage is the computing resources.

What would you advise?

Comment: SSH private keys are supposed to be stored encrypted *already*. Can't you just reject keys without a passphrase?

Comment: I could. But I don't want to. Some of our staff prefer to save keys without a passphrase and we want to support them as well.